# How to write strings from foreach loop to console one line at a time?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a solution to get the name and id of a set of tests from an API. All of the data is found and returned as I can see the data in the Output window in Visual Studio.

```
// method to get the test names and id numbers
    public List<Asset> GetTests()
    {
        var assetType = _context.MetaModel.GetAssetType("Test");
        var query = new Query(assetType);
        var nameAttribute = assetType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name");


        query.Selection.Add(nameAttribute);

        var result = _context.Services.Retrieve(query);

        result.Assets.ForEach(test =>
            LogResult(test.Oid.Token,
                GetValue(test.GetAttribute(nameAttribute).Value)));

        return result.Assets;
    }
```

I have two other methods, one to check for null values and the other to display the output to the Output window in Visual Studio.

```
    private static string GetValue(object value)
    {
        return value == null ? "No Value Available" : value.ToString();
    }

    private static void LogResult(params string[] results)
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(result);
        }
    }
```

When I step through the code I see that the two values, id number and test name, are displaying to the console window successfully. The data is displayed in the output window in one line.

`Test:1142Sample: Login Criterion Test:1147Sample: Add Customer Details CriterionTest:1153Sample: Add Customer Header`

Of course if I write out to the console the results are all jumbled together.

How do you display the results in the Console Window as:

```
    Test:1142     Name: Login Criterion
    Test:11475    Name: Add Customer Details
    Test:1153     Name: Add Customer Header
```

Basically, the output is correct but I would like to format the data to display neatly in the Console Window.

I see an example here, http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-writeline, but it looks like you have to know how many values will be returned in order to format the display correctly. Would you use an array to achieve this?

```
static void Main()
{
string value1 = "Dot";
string value2 = "Net";
string value3 = "Perls";

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", // <-- This is called a format string.
    value1,                        // <-- These are substitutions.
    value2,
    value3);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can do this directly in the `ForEach` delegate, like this:

```
result.Assets.ForEach(test =>
    Console.WriteLine("Test:{0,-9}Name: {1}",
        test.Oid.Token,
        GetValue(test.GetAttribute(nameAttribute).Value)));
```

Note: the `-9` in the format string specifies the width of that string in the output. It pads that parameter with up to 9 spaces so that the second string will be aligned correctly.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That was quoted from an article. From the output in the question, it appears OP's was actually using `Write`.

Comment: OK, missed that was article quote

Comment: Beautiful solution, why did you use -9 for the second number? {0,-9} What happens if you change that second number?

Comment: @ma3str0 Sorry, I meant to make a note of that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might use this

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(result + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

or this

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

or `p.s.w.g` answer is very good too.

Comment: Correct, but I think you don't need Environment.NewLine in second case

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ah yeah just forgot it there :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `Debug.Print` and `String.Format`:

```
foreach (string result in results)
{
    Debug.Print(string.Format("{0, -14} {1}", test.Oid.Token, 
                GetValue(test.GetAttribute(nameAttribute).Value)));
}
```